# how to separate parts of long mathematical algorithm?

Tags: oop

I have several pages of code. It's pretty ugly because it's doing a lot of "calculation" etc. But it contains of several phases, like many algorthims, like that:

1. calculate orders I want to leave
2. kill orders I want to leave but I can't leave because of volume restrictions
3. calculate orders I want to add
4. kill other orders I want to leave but I can't because of new orders
5. adjust new orders ammount to fit desired volume

Totally I have 5 pages of ugly code which I want to separate at least by stage. But I don't want to introduce separate method for each stage, because these stages make sense only together, stage itself is useless so I think it would be wrong to create separate method for each stage.

I think I should use c# `#region` for separation, what do you think, will you suggest something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid #region directives for this purpose, they only sweep dirt under the carpet.

I second @RasmusFranke's advice, divide et impera: while separating functionalities into methods you may notice that a bunch of methods happen to represent a concept which is class-worthy, then you can move the methods in a new class. **Reusability is not the only reason to create methods**.

Refactor, refactor, refactor. Keep in mind principles like [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) while using techniques from [Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) and [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052).

Take it slow and use if you can tools like Resharper or Refactor! Pro which help to minimize mistakes that could occur while refactoring.

Use your tests to check if you broke anything, especially if you do not have access to the previously mentioned tools or if you are doing some major refactoring. If you don't have tests try to write some, even if it may be daunting to write tests for legacy code.

Last but not least, do not touch it if you don't need to. If it works but it is "ugly" and it is not a part of your code needing changes, let it be.

Answer (score 1):

Use private methods to seperate logic into small tasks, even if said logic is only used in one place, it increases readability of code by a lot.